# Determining Instantaneous Upload and Download Speed in Android

Tags: android, bandwidth

Is there any way by which i can determine instantaneous upload and download bandwidth available at a particular time in Android.

Is it must to upload or download some data to determine the available bandwidth ?

Comment: Yes, you must upload or download data to determine bandwidth. Take a look at [this library](https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class) from Facebook which does just that.

Comment: @Eran Is it Possible to determine the speeds using TrafficStats class of Android. which contains functions like getTotalTxBytes() and by dividing this by time for a particular duration can i achieve this.?